# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un arreglo de un listview en android?

Tags: android, json, array, gson

Que tal, quisiera saber como puedo recorrer un arreglo, ya tengo los datos que vienen desde un Web service, pero el arreglo no se recorre como se puede ver en la captura de pantalla,  aclaro el primer registro esta vació por eso aparece sin nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que implemente para poder intentar que se recorriera el arreglo pero al parecer no lo hace.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
        super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
        dialogAsynk.dismiss();

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Tamaño del arrego: " + itemEmpresases.size());

        DaoEmpresas myDao = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());
        ItemEmpresas myEmpresa = new ItemEmpresas();

        myEmpresa.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(0).getNombre());

        for (int i = 0; i == itemEmpresases.size(); i++){

            if (itemEmpresases.size()>=i ){
                if (myDao.insertEmpresa(myEmpresa) == true){
                    Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                    reload();
                }
            }else {
                Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
            }
        }
```

Y esta es una captura del log para ver el tamaño que tiene el arreglo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización**

> 03-08 12:47:56.863 10752-10752/com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app, PID: 10752
>                                                                                           java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 20, size is 20
>                                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                               at com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.sigc11.Concesionarios$EmpresaEnSegundoPlano.onPostExecute(Concesionarios.java:161)
>                                                                                               at com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.sigc11.Concesionarios$EmpresaEnSegundoPlano.onPostExecute(Concesionarios.java:137)
>                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

*Si se recorre el arreglo pero se detiene la aplicación*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Modificación en el código*

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
        super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
        dialogAsynk.dismiss();

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Tamaño del arrego: " + itemEmpresases.size());

        DaoEmpresas myDao = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());
        for (int i = 0; i <= itemEmpresases.size(); i++){
            ItemEmpresas myEmp = new ItemEmpresas();
            myEmp.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(i).getNombre());
            if (itemEmpresases.size()>=i ){
                if (myDao.insertEmpresa(myEmp) == true){
                    Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                    reload();
                }
            }else {
                Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más adecuado y optimizado para recorrer el `ArrayList` sería de esta forma :

```
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
            super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
            dialogAsynk.dismiss();

            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Tamaño del arrego: " + itemEmpresases.size());

            DaoEmpresas myDao = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());

/************ Recorrer ArrayList *************************/    
        for(ItemEmpresas empresa: itemEmpresases){
                if (myDao.insertEmpresa(empresa) == true){
                    Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                    reload();
                }else{
                    Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
                }
        }
/*************************************/

           /* for (int i = 0; i <= itemEmpresases.size(); i++){
                ItemEmpresas myEmp = new ItemEmpresas();
                myEmp.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(i).getNombre());
                if (itemEmpresases.size()>=i ){
                    if (myDao.insertEmpresa(myEmp) == true){
                        Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                        reload();
                    }
                }else {
                    Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
                }
            }*/

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder de nuevo, "myEmpresa" sale de esta instancia "ItemEmpresas myEmpresa = new ItemEmpresas();"?

Comment: Es que intente meter ese foreach pero me marca un error en "myEpresa"

Comment: Hola Alexis, perdón es "empresa", la explicación es : obtiene los elementos tipo ItemEmpresas de itemEmpresases, cada elemento en cada bucle será "empresa", revisa nuevamente.

Comment: muchas gracias tambien funciono y supongo que es la forma mas optima de recorrer el arreglo, solo que el mensaje de actualizado tambien entra en el bucle y se muestra como 20 veces jajaja pero de verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Te recomiendo uses un for( en este caso ya que al tener tu lista demasiados datos, esta es la forma mà ràpida de obtener sus elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas compañero Alexis creo que el error en el codigo viene en el ciclo for y la asignacion fija de la posicion del listview el cual tienes:

myEmpresa.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(0).getNombre());

en donde deverias pasar un valor de la posición en tu .get(i) como por ejemplo:

myEmpresa.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(i).getNombre());

y lo otro del ciclo for veo que lo tienes asi:

for (int i = 0; i == itemEmpresases.size(); i++){

```
        if (itemEmpresases.size()>=i ){
            if (myDao.insertEmpresa(myEmpresa) == true){
                Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                reload();
            }
        }else {
            Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
        }
    }
```

y tu condicion i==  itemEmpresases.size() no se cumple, esto deberia ser  condicion i<= itemEmpresases.size() , favor probar y avisar si te sirvió de algo, en caso contrario elimino sin problema esta respuesta si no fue de utilidad un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo compañero y claro que reportaré el resultado, saludos

Comment: @Nicethuder que tal, puse las modificaciones que le hice al codigo con los resultados y si funciona solo que se detiene la aplicación

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara el recorrido, creo que el error que te emite es por poner for (int i = 0; i <= itemEmpresases.size(); i++) y como se comienza en 0 tiene que ser for (int i = 0; i < itemEmpresases.size(); i++) ya que el index 20 no deberia existir al ser su tamaño 20 el maximo es 19 creería que es por eso.

Comment: Si era eso, muchas gracias de verdad, llevaba atorado con esto un par de días, de verdad te agradezco mucho la ayuda